# n+1 selects with bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to eagerly fetch the entire entity graph with Spring Data JPA but getting n+1 selects I believe due to the bidirectional relationship in my entities.
I have the following Parent, Child and Grandchild entities (simplified version of legacy tables);

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long identity;

    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Child> children;

    private Set<Child> getChildrenInternal() {
        if (this.children == null) {
            this.children = new HashSet<>();
        }
        return this.children;
    }

    public Parent addChild(Child child) {
        getChildrenInternal().add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Parent)) return false;
        Parent parent = (Parent) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), parent.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@IdClass(ChildKey.class)
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long identity;

    @Id
    private String child_col;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "child")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Grandchild> grandchildren;

    private Set<Grandchild> getGrandchildrenInternal() {
        if (this.grandchildren == null) {
            this.grandchildren= new HashSet<>();
        }
        return this.grandchildren;
    }

    public Child addGrandchild(Grandchild grandchild) {
        getGrandchildrenInternal().add(grandchild);
        grandchild.setChild(this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Parent)) return false;
        Child child = (Child) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getChild_col(), child.getChild_col())
                && Objects.equals(parent, child.getParent());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getChild_col(), getParent());
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@IdClass(GrandchildKey.class)
public class Grandchild implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long identity;

    @Id
    private String grandchild_col;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "parent_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_col", referencedColumnName = "child_col")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Child child;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Parent)) return false;
        Grandchild grandchild = (Grandchild) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getGrandchild_col(), grandchild.getGrandchild_col())
                && Objects.equals(child, grandchild.getChild());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getGrandchild_col(), getChild());
    }
}
```

with keys;

```
public class ChildKey implements Serializable {
    private String child_col;
    private Parent parent;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Child)) return false;
        Child child = (Child) obj;
        return Objects.equals(child_col, child.getChild_col())
                && Objects.equals(parent, child.getParent());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(child_col, parent);
    }
}

public class GrandchildKey implements Serializable {
    private String grandchild_col;
    private Child child;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Grandchild)) return false;
        Grandchild grandchild = (Grandchild) obj;
        return Objects.equals(grandchild_col, grandchild.getGrandchild_col())
                && Objects.equals(child, grandchild.getChild());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(grandchild_col, child);
    }
}
```

and JPA repository;

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Parent p " +
            "JOIN FETCH p.children c " +
            "JOIN FETCH c.grandchildren")
    List<Parent> testFind();
}
```

Hibernate is generating the following sql;

```
select
        parent0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        children1_.child_col as child_co1_0_1_,
        children1_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_1_,
        grandchild2_.child_col as child_co3_1_2_,
        grandchild2_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_2_,
        grandchild2_.grandchild_col as grandchi1_1_2_,
        parent0_.identity as identity2_2_0_,
        children1_.identity as identity2_0_1_,
        children1_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0__,
        children1_.child_col as child_co1_0_0__,
        grandchild2_.identity as identity2_1_2_,
        grandchild2_.child_col as child_co3_1_1__,
        grandchild2_.parent_id as parent_i4_1_1__,
        grandchild2_.grandchild_col as grandchi1_1_1__ 
    from
        parent parent0_ 
    inner join
        child children1_ 
            on parent0_.id=children1_.parent_id 
    inner join
        grandchild grandchild2_ 
            on children1_.child_col=grandchild2_.child_col 
            and children1_.parent_id=grandchild2_.parent_id
```

then additional statements for each parent and child;

```
select
        parent0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        parent0_.identity as identity2_2_0_ 
    from
        parent parent0_ 
    where
        parent0_.id=?

select
        child0_.child_col as child_co1_0_0_,
        child0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_,
        child0_.identity as identity2_0_0_,
        parent1_.id as id1_2_1_,
        parent1_.identity as identity2_2_1_ 
    from
        child child0_ 
    inner join
        parent parent1_ 
            on child0_.parent_id=parent1_.id 
    where
        child0_.child_col=? 
        and child0_.parent_id=?
```

Is there a way to eliminate the additional selects without making the relationships uni-directional?

Comment: Have you implemented equals() and hashcode() on the ID classes?

Comment: You also appear to be missing an @Id on the child property on Grandchild.

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the equals() and hashCode() and also the missing @ID field. The SQL generated by hibernate is the same though.

Comment: equals() and hashcode() **on the ID classes** not the entities.

Comment: sorry, added the equals and hashcode to the Id classes but unfortunately the sql remains the same. Also the equals and hashcode functions dont appear to be getting hit for the Id classes.

Comment: ? `!(obj instanceof Parent))` ?

Comment: updated. Still no change in behaviour